# Web app to manage subscriptions, handling payment and reminders

Tags: web-apps, ecommerce

Is there a web app that would allow to easily manage the selling  of subscriptions of products. For example, a subscription to coffee from a coffee shop. The app would allow the owner of the shop to set up an account, and coffee-drinkers to subscribe to a bag of coffee per week/month/whatever. The app would automatically charge the credit card and notify the owner of the order so that the coffee gets delivered.

If this doesn't exist and enough people want it, I might consider making it: http://goo.gl/forms/wcx2ktJzvB

Comment: Did you come around making it? Did you find something?